# get the place from 4 points

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of 4 integers, which represent the scores of 4 players. I want to get another array that gives me the ranking of the players based on their scores.

For example: 
Given the scores {10,20,15,40}

I want the ranking to be {4,2,3,1}

The lowest score being rank 4 and the highest score being rank 1.

The biggest problem is when there are multiple players with the same score. For example {10,10,20,40} then I want to get {34,34,2,1} (34 because the third and fourth place are shared by two players)

Another example is {40,40,10,20}, which should give the ranking {12,12,4,3} (12 for shared first and second place)

I have for the moment two dubble arrays to come to that result, but I think it can be better, but I don't find how. My biggest problem now is when we have 3 same scores: {40,40,40,10} than I should have the result {123,123,123,4}

I hope you understand my question and of course can help me to find a solution.

thanks

Comment: I would love to help, but I don't know what you need. What have you tried and how is your code not working?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels same here, I didn't get anything, but why don't you use a Map? like HashMap<Double,Double>

Comment: What is the algorithm that decides how many points to give these numbers? I don't really understand your question

Comment: This seems to be a very poor modeling. Using two dependent arrays that must be kept in sync. How about using a PlayerScore class that associates players with their score. Put them into a priority queue (a max-heap) and you will always be able to iterate them in the right order.

Comment: Returning 34 for 3/4 seens very very dangerous. What if you have 15 players and 1st and second are in equal place; i.e. 12th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create indices that we will sort using the scores:

```
final double[] scores = // acquire scores
Integer[] indices = new Integer[scores.length];
Arrays.sort(indexes, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
        return -Double.compare(scores[i], scores[j]);
    }
});
```

Note that we use a `-` to sort in *descending* order.

Now, we have a ordered our scores using `indices`, and accounted for the possibility of repeated scores. Next, we will collect all the indices for each score. We will do this by building a map from scores to lists of indices for that score.

```
Map<Double, SortedSet<Integer>> map =
    new HashMap<Double, SortedSet<Integer>>();
for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if(!map.containsKey(scores[i])) {
        map.puts(scores[i], new TreeSet<Integer>());
    }
    map.get(scores[i]).add(indexes[i] + 1);
}
```

We use `SortedSet` so that the indices come out in order and we add `1` because your ranks start at one instead of zero.

Now, if you iterate over the scores, you can look up the ranks from the `HashMap`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    SortedSet<Integer> set = map.get(scores[i]);
    System.out.print(scores[i] + ": ");
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
    System.out.print(iterator.next());
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print("," + iterator.next());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

When I run this on your example `[40, 40, 10, 20]`, I see the output:

```
40: 1,2
40: 1,2
10: 3
20: 4
```

and on `[40, 40, 40, 10]`:

```
40: 1,2,3
40: 1,2,3
40: 1,2,3
10: 4
```

and on `[10, 10, 20, 40]`:

```
10: 3,4
10: 3,4
20: 2
40: 1
```

From here, it should be easy to modify to get your desired rankings.

Let's walk through how this works mentally. We'll use the example `[40, 40, 10, 20]`. First, we build indexes:

```
indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Then we sort indexes using the scores;

```
indexes = [0, 1, 3, 2]
```

Then we collect all the ranks for each score (remember, we add one to the indexes from the previous step):

```
map = { 40 : [1, 2], 10 : [4], 20 : [3] }
```

Then, for each score in `scores`, we can look up all the ranks in `map` and dump them to the console.